# I want to select values in date range from the drop down.how can I select the values as date in the year range date picker

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently working on Selenium WebDriver and using Java.I want to select values in date range from the drop down.. I want to know how can I select the values as Date, Month and year in the year range date picker

HTML Code:

```html
<html>

<head>

  <body>
    <div class="display_wait_overlay">
      <div class="section wrapper">
        <div id="test-not" class="fade modal text-left">
          <div id="monthlyinvoiceremainder" class="fade modal text-left">
            <div id="monthlyinvoiceremainderBox" class="btm_bx">
              <div id="depositDetailsResponse" class="fade modal text-left">
                <div id="depositDetails" class="fade modal text-left">
                  <footer class="footer navbar_custom" style="">
                    <div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-bottom" style="display: block; top: 155.933px; left: 758.133px;">
                      <div class="datepicker-days" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none;">
                          <div class="datepicker-years" style="display: block;">
                            <table class="table-condensed">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;">«</th>
                                  <th class="datepicker-switch" colspan="5">2010-2019</th>
                                  <th class="next" style="visibility: hidden;">»</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td colspan="7">
                                    <span class="year old">2009</span>
                                    <span class="year">2010</span>
                                    <span class="year">2011</span>
                                    <span class="year">2012</span>
                                    <span class="year">2013</span>
                                    <span class="year">2014</span>
                                    <span class="year">2015</span>
                                    <span class="year disabled">2016</span>
                                    <span class="year disabled">2017</span>
                                    <span class="year disabled">2018</span>
                                    <span class="year disabled">2019</span>
                                    <span class="year new disabled">2020</span>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                              <tfoot>
                            </table>
                          </div>
                        </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Some code that you tried would be helpful here. If not, try posting URL or HTML of the date picker.

Comment: HTML: `<div class="datepicker-years" style="display: block;">'
'<table class="table-condensed">'
'class="prev" style="visibility: visible;">«<'
'class="datepicker-switch" colspan="5">2010-2019'
' class="next" style="visibility: hidden;">»<'

Comment: ' colspan="7">'
' class="year old">2009<'
' class="year">2010<'
' class="year">2011<'
' class="year">2012<'
' class="year">2013<'
' class="year">2014<'
' class="year">2015<'
' class="year disabled">2016<'
' class="year disabled">2017<'
' class="year disabled">2018<'
' class="year disabled">2019<'
' class="year new disabled">2020<`

Comment: Edit your question and add this `HTML` in there itself. Meanwhile, checking on your question for possible solution.

Comment: No this `HTML` do not result anything. Please properly format html code in question itself.

Comment: @AbhayYadav  can you **add the screenshots of how the datepicker UI changes?** the `HTML` you provided has so much css class styles, which are not really useful to provide answer to you. Also post the code what you have tried to solve your problem.

Comment: I am not able to add screenshot in my query.

Comment: In date picker, there is range of 10 years displayed by default i.e. 2010 - 2019 and Previous button enabled to select the date from the previous years. I need to click on Previous button twice and want to select an year displayed in list then need to select a month then Date.

Comment: Code recorded using Selenium IDE and Format is TestNG:

selenium.open("/employeeadd");
selenium.click("css=div.datepicker-years > table.table-condensed > thead > tr > th.prev");
selenium.click("css=div.datepicker-years > table.table-condensed > thead > tr > th.prev");
selenium.click("//div[@id='sizzle-1450767033679']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/span[2]");
selenium.click("//div[@id='sizzle-1450767033679']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/span[6]");
  selenium.click("//div[@id='sizzle-1450767033679']/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]");